# How to Check the empty text fields before uploading image or video in android?

Tags: android

I'm new to stackoverflow and android, sorry if i'm wrong. I am trying to check the text fields is empty or not, when the text field is empty, upload button should show please enter title and when user enters the text then only it should upload the image. After entering title then also it again shows the toast.

```
 btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         if (title1.matches("")){
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter the Title and Category", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         } else if(description1.matches("")){
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Select Category", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         } else {
             flag = 1;
             // uploading the file to server
             new UploadFileToServer().execute();
         }
     }
 });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It's not clear...

Comment: What are `description1` and `title1` ? TextView ? String ?

Comment: tittle1 and description1 are Srings

Answer (score 0):

try this.

Place this code in your button onClickListener:

```
     String mText = mEditText.getText().toString();

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(mText)){

               //Do what you want(Edittext is NULL)

            }else{

            //Do what you want(Not NULL)     

         }
```

Answer (score 0):

To check for empty fields, use

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText().toString())) {
// do something
}
```

or if you want to check if string is empty or null use -

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(stringToCheck) {
    // do something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get value from your edittext like below:

Globally declare variable : -

```
String editvalue;
```

In onCreate() :-

```
EditText youredittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.youredittextid);
editvalue = youredittext.getText.toString().trim();
```

Now in your condition check :

```
if(editvalue.isEmpty() || editvalue == null){

// Do what you want when editText's value is null or empty

}else{

}
```

You can also use

[TextUtils.isEmpty(CharSequence str)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

for empty and null string check.

> Returns true if the string is null or 0-length

Comment: `TextUtils.isEmpty()` is better than using a normal `equals()` since it will also perform a `null` check. This will prevent any error in the future and is a good practice.

Comment: @RohanKandwal : I am totally agree with you and i have just put my answer as what I thought.

Comment: I am not saying what you wrote isn't correct in this scenario, just telling you something to improve upon. We all are here to be better coder, right?

Comment: @RohanKandwal : Please see my update. I already did that.And Thanks for your valuable suggestion.

Comment: Guys please help me with this.. After entering title, then also it again shows the toast.

Comment: @Shivaraj : Please provide your java class .